# All of my texts disappeared, what can I do?

Tags: sms, data-recovery

All of my old text messages disappeared. What might I be able to do to recover them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a previous backup, there's no *easy* way to recover them.

Use Handcent or GoSMS - they have in-built scheduling to backup SMS to your SD card or to send the backup to an email mailbox you specify.

Comment: Maybe you want to correct your "no way" to "no easy way" or "no way without root". But agreed: nothing for the "average user" to easily achieve...

Answer (score 3):

**SPOILER: The following does only work on rooted devices!**

If they are already gone, in most cases it's too late. However, some chances are left if your device is rooted -- but they are not that easy to achieve: You would need a complete (physical) file system copy from your internal storage, and pull that to your workstation. Once you've achieved that, you can use a process called [File Carving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_carving) to get hold of even deleted files. This might get especially tricky as most devices use [YAFFS2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAFFS) for their internal storage -- a file system rarely used on any workstation.

Some File Carving software solutions include:

- [Scalpel](http://www.digitalforensicssolutions.com/Scalpel/) available for Linux (prefered), Mac OS X, Windows
- [foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/) Linux; can also work on Images created with `dd` -- so if you were able to create such on your device, the YAFFS2 barrier is gone)
- [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) supports a lot of operating systems

Concerning this special case (especially with YAFFS2), I'd say the best approach would be to go with a `dd` image and foremost. As on YAFFS2 things are not that lightly "deleted or wiped" (to prolong the life of NAND-Flash, "stuff" is rather marked deleted and only overwritten when that storage block is needed to store new data), chances are quite good to recover "stuff".

Not everybody's easiest way, I know -- but there's no "easy solution" I could see.

Comment: Remark:You might also want to check [Recover deleted content from userdata partition?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25948/recover-deleted-content-from-userdata-partition), which especially deals with deleted SMS and offers additional details. Quoting: *So it came to pass, that Amanda did have a blonde moment and deleted all her threads in the SMS app by mistake.*