# Any suggestion on how to recover deleted sms?

Tags: sms, data-recovery

Yesterday I just picked my phone from my pocket and it was prompting me to delete all my messages, and I accidentally tapped the confirm button and lost all my messages.

I don't have any backup and my phone is not rooted. Is possible to recover it?

Comment: If you use the search box on top of this page, and enter [recover deleted sms](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=recover+deleted+sms), it turns up some helpful questions which do have answers. Have you checked e.g. with [Is there a way to recover a deleted SMS?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5414/16575) / [HTC Desire crashed, deleted all SMS/MMS. Can I recover?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5478/16575) / [Recover deleted content from userdata partition?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25948/16575)

Comment: Yes, but all those questions have answers about having backup or rooted phones.

Comment: For good reasons: There's no other way.

Comment: Thanks!
So, my question is not a total duplicate, and the answer is 'No'.

Comment: Depending on the phone you might still root it by the way. What model do you own?

Comment: @ce4 It's a S3 Mini. Do you think I can root it and still recover the messages?

Comment: The S3 mini can be rooted afterwards, yep. You might have luck to root without loosing data and **then** possibly have even more luck to recover it using the techniques in the other answers linked here.

Comment: Most Samsung phones have unlocked bootloaders. It'll void your warranty though and alter your firmware. So it's not for the faint of heart, you'd flash the recovery from [this Rom thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2384232) (don't do a full install and **no wipe**!) and boot into CWM to grab a flash dump.