# How do I recover deleted text messages and attachments on Samsung Galaxy Note10+?

Tags: samsung, sms, data-recovery

While attempting to delete an SMS ad on Samsung Galaxy Note10+, I did not notice that every message in my log was checked and I deleted my entire text history.

How do I recover deleted text messages and picture attachments on it?

Comment: Without root permissions (to extract the SMS database), hardly possible. For some background, see [this Q&A](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/5478/16575) – a little aged, but basically still valid.